# Firebase + Ionic Framework: Chat notifications

Tags: notifications, firebase, ionic-framework

SO I am wondering if its possible to implement some sort of notifications with Firebase and Ionic Framework, which I am using to create app. Can I stick with Firebase only, or do I need to get some other service, such as for example Parse?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I got Parse working - awesome. THe only thing that doesnt really work for me is the following code:

```
function sendNotification(deviceToken, content){
  console.log('targetDevice is: ' + deviceToken);
  console.log('content is:' + content);
  var notificationEndpoint = AY_Parse.parseEndpoint + "/1/push";
  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Parse-Application-Id': AY_Parse.parseApplicationId,
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': AY_Parse.parseRestApiKey
  };
  var pushNotification = $resource(notificationEndpoint, {},
    {
      'save': {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: headers
      }
    });
 var registerNotification = new pushNotification();
 registerNotification.deviceToken = deviceToken;
 registerNotification.data = {alert: content};
  console.log(registerNotification);
  console.log(angular.toJson(registerNotification));
  return registerNotification.$save;
}
```

It should send Push notificaiton to the targeted device, however it does nothing..

ANSWER:

Ok, the problem was with the following line:

```
 registerNotification.deviceToken = deviceToken;
```

Changed to:

```
     registerNotification.where= {deviceToken: deviceToken};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure about Firebase but using Parse was easy to follow and understand, I managed to get everything working perfectly with the ngCordova Push Notifications.

https://parse.com/products/push
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/
https://www.parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

I hope these help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Can you tell me how did you handle Peer 2 Peer notification sending? Or do you just send data to Parse server with the recipient tokenID, and message inside?

Comment: Also I found this on Github, might be helpful.
https://github.com/arun0009/ionicapp

Comment: Absolutely no problem! @uksz

Comment: Hey Adam, So I am storing device tokens into my Firebase account, however, I dont really know how to register devices onto Parse account. Could you give me any tutorial on that?

Comment: Ok, I got everything working. I have one additional question with code that I've uploaded to the original post